# Why Joda and Calendar print different times?

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

Why are these 2 debug lines print different hours?

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5");    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);    
DateTime dt = new DateTime(cal);    
System.out.println("1 ====> " + dt.toString());  
System.out.println("2 ====> " + cal.getTime());
```

2nd line shows current time.
1st line shows time in proper timezone.

Answer (score 5):

The method `getTime()` in `Calendar` returns a `Date` object. A `Date` object does not have a time zone. It just represents the time in milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 at midnight, in the UTC time zone. When printed, it uses the default time zone, unless you use a `DateFormat` that was set with a time zone.

Joda-Time's `DateTime` is an object that includes time zone. When it is created from a `Calendar` object, it takes that calendar's time zone.

So when you create a `Date` from a `Calendar`, you lose the time zone information. When you create a `DateTime` from a `Calendar`, you get to keep the time zone information.

Comment: I guess it is some design decision, but if I instantiate the calendar with a timezone why can't the Date returned be configured accordingly?

Comment: @Jim Because a `Date` object doesn't have a time zone component. It represents the same instance that the calendar represents - which is the instance of creation of the `Calendar` object in your case. The only thing that's different between the `Calendar` and the `Date` is that the `Calendar` has information that tells it to calculate the fields (hour, minute) based on the given time zone. `Date` doesn't have that extra information. It's a simpler object.

Comment: Yes that what I was expecting. That calendar would instantiate such a `Date` object with the proper information.

Comment: @Jim, it **is** the proper information. It represents the exact same instance. It just doesn't have time zone. Try creating a `DateFormat` with the appropriate time zone and printing the `Date` object that you got, and you'll see that you get the same time as in the `DateTime` object.